# "requested physical block size 2048 is not supported by this disk" - unable to create google compute disk using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i want to create a gcloud compute disk so in order to achieve i wrote below code

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "default2" {
name  = "test-disk"
type  = "pd-balanced"
zone  = "us-central1-a"
image = "centos-7-v20210609"
physical_block_size_bytes = 20480
}
```

when i run terraform apply it show following error
[image: error]

how can i fix this

Comment: Why are you using the value `20480` for `physical_block_size_bytes`? A typical value is 4096.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk#argument-reference)

> physical_block_size_bytes - (Optional) Physical block size of the persistent disk, in bytes. If not present in a request, a default value is used. Currently supported sizes are 4096 and 16384, other sizes may be added in the future. If an unsupported value is requested, the error message will list the supported values for the caller's project.